# Find email in a list - exact search?

Tags: php

I'm having a bit of a problem with searching for a string. I'm using the XMLAPI from cPanel to list all the email account that's on my cPanel. Then, I want to search the user's input with what is on the list, to see if the email already exist. However, the problem is that :

If the new email is 1 letter, for example : 1@domain.com
And if 1 of the email on the list **END** with the number 1 --> josh1@domain.com, the search will say that 1@domain.com is on the list.

Here is what the list looks like :

```
{
    "cpanelresult": {
        "event": {
            "result": 1
        },
        "data": [{
            "email": "1@domain.com",
            "login": "1@domain.com"
        }, {
            "email": "10@domain.com",
            "login": "10@domain.com"
        }, {
            "email": "11@domain.com",
            "login": "11@domain.com"
        }, {
            "email": "5@domain.com",
            "login": "5@domain.com"
        }, {
            "email": "8@domain.com",
            "login": "8@domain.com"
        }, {
            "email": "9@domain.com",
            "login": "9@domain.com"
        }, {
            "email": "admin@domain.com",
            "login": "admin@domain.com"
        }, {
            "email": "auth@domain.com",
            "login": "auth@domain.com"
        }, {
            "email": "cai@domain.com",
            "login": "cai@domain.com"
        }, {
            "email": "estoris@domain.com",
            "login": "estoris@domain.com"
        }, {
            "email": "johndoe@domain.com",
            "login": "johndoe@domain.com"
        }, {
            "email": "maplex111@domain.com",
            "login": "maplex111@domain.com"
        }, {
            "email": "**maplex222@domain.com**",
            "login": "maplex222@domain.com"
        }, {
            "email": "patrickroxs@domain.com",
            "login": "patrickroxs@domain.com"
        }, {
            "email": "test@domain.com",
            "login": "test@domain.com"
        }, {
            "email": "amail",
            "login": "Main 
Account"
        }],
        "func": "listpops",
        "module": "Email",
        "apiversion": 2
    }
}
```

This is what I did to try and find the email :

```
     if(preg_match("/2@domain.com/",$try) == true) {
     echo 'Found the email!';
     } else {
     echo 'Did not find email';
     }
```

That code said that the email is on the list, when it is not. So how do I do this?

Comment: If the data is returned as JSON, why not parse it and iterate accordingly until you find it?

Comment: I tried putting in admin@domain.com (on the list) and the result is "not found"

Comment: im with austin on this.. but why not just `strstr($list, '1@domain.com');` ?

Comment: Because if there is another account that is named 1111@domain.com on the list, strstr would say that 1@domain.com is already taken, when it is not

Comment: You should `json_decode()` it first, then do regular search.

Answer (score 0):

You're not matching the double quotes.

```
 if(preg_match('/"' + email + '"/',$try) == true) {
     echo 'Found the email!';
 } else {
     echo 'Did not find email';
 }
```